# .htaccess file is causing 404 errors with AJAX

Tags: .htaccess, jquery, mod-rewrite

Everything is working on my localhost, where the .htaccess file is not being used. But when I go to the actual site I am having a problem with AJAX requests. I figured out that the part causing the problem is the removal of the .php extension.

Here is my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## redirect to 404 page when file does not exist
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

## clean urls for blog.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+blog\.php\?title=([^\s&]+)&? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog/%1? [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^blog/([\w-+]+)/?$ /blog.php?title=$1 [L]

## remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index
RewriteRule ^(.*)index$ /$1 [R=301,L]

## To remove .php file extension
## RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
## RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,NC]
## RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
## RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php
```

by commenting out the last four lines it fixed the problem. But I want to be able to remove .php and still use ajax for things like forms.

Here is the ajax

```
$.ajax({
     type:'post',
     url:'inc/example.php',
     data:$data,
     async:false,
     success:function(){
         console.log('success');
     },
     error:function(r){
         console.log(r.responseText);
     }
});
```

The error function in the ajax is displaying my 404 error page. I tried removing the .php from the url in the ajax request, no good. Then I tried navigating to inc/example.php and I got the 404 page. The .htaccess file is at the root, and the page making the ajax request is one directory below the root, so the 404 error is happening two directories deep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to exclude redirecting POST requests. Your ajax code submits to `example.php` via a POST, and when the rule redirects you to a URL without the `php` extension, you lose the request body. You should make the condition match only against GET and HEAD requests:

```
## To remove .php file extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2 [R,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php
```